# How to draw swt image?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to draw an swt Image but nothing appears:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.open();

Image image = new Image(display, "C:/sample_image.png");
Rectangle bounds = image.getBounds();

GC gc = new GC(image);
gc.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
// gc.drawLine(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
// gc.drawLine(0, bounds.height, bounds.width, 0);
// gc.dispose();
// image.dispose();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

I have tested that the image exists and has content - any ideas?

Comment: Where do you want to draw this image on?

Comment: On my display. The shell is opened but empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show up an image with swt in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447455/how-to-show-up-an-image-with-swt-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a Label and set the image on it.

```
Image myImage = new Image( display, "C:/sample_image.png" );
Label myLabel = new Label( shell, SWT.NONE );
myLabel.setImage( myImage );
```

That may be enough for you.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, one uses the Canvas to draw an image.

```
// Create a canvas
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
final Image image = new Image(display, "C:/sample_image.png");

// Create a paint handler for the canvas    
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
  public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
    e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);        
  }
});
```

See [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html) for more info on SWT Images.